# php how to get all values array but array_values not working?

Tags: php

how to get all values array but set all keys the same name
ex :
[this is my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdsAo.png)

but i need remove this key .. I have used array_values() .. but not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lx7c.png)

Comment: You can't remove those ones. They are identifiers of your multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to grab all the arrays inside the `item` keys? Using `array_column` and specifying the `item` as the key will return the arrays inside each `item` key in a new array. If that is what you're after? The question was kind of hard to understand IMHO.

```php
array_column($array, 'item');
```

This will return an array on the following structure.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ttt
            [price] => 100
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => sss
            [price] => 100
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => vvv
            [price] => 100
            [quantity] => 1
        )
)
```

Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/kdSvc) showing it working.